# how to find out if a company has stock/shares to invest in?

Tags: stocks, investing, small-business, shares, private-company

Scenario: Lets say I'm walking down main street and a company or two catch my eye as possible investment opportunities.

How do I go about finding if they have stock/shares to invest in? Some may say just look up the name of the company but some websites like "Robinhood" do not have all possible companies that sell stocks (they add more over time). Some of these companies have many retail stores in the US.

I hope my intent in this question came across.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do i go about finding if they have stock/shares to invest in?

You can visit the company's website and see if there is an "investor relations" section.

Or check on a major brokerage website.

> some websites like "Robinhood" does not have all possible companies that sell stocks (they add more over time).

So use a better website. Preferably use your broker's website, because even if the company does have publicly traded shares they aren't much good to you if they aren't available through your broker (and if you're using a major broker like Fidelity or Schwab and the other company isn't available there, then it's probably so thinly traded that you don't want to invest in it).

Answer (score 0):

Google: "Look up stock symbols"

You'll find lots of web sites that offer free symbol look up.  Some popular ones are:

https://finance.yahoo.com/lookup/

https://www.marketwatch.com/tools/quotes/lookup.asp

https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/